Using INCLUDE with WHERE in PostgresSQL index
I have found usages of creating indexes with WHERE and INCLUDE operators at some project migrations. The index creation looks like:
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY IF NOT EXISTS some_index 
ON some_table USING btree(some_column) 
INCLUDE (status)
WHERE status = 'Done';

And the query looks like this:
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE status = 'Done' and some_column = 'abcd'

I think that INCLUDE operator has no sense here cause there is no filtration on status column and  some_index will be applied without some filtration on column if we make query. So index without include will be as faster as index with this operator.
May be there are some other reasons to use INCLUDE in partial index in such situation?

You use include when you want to perform index only scan. Index with include has ability to return the contents of non-key columns without having to visit the index's table
In short when you want to leverage the benefit of index-only scan, whatever you put in Select has to be included in include
In your case, instead of select *, use select status
And yes, to answer your question for the query you have given, index without include will be faster

Thanks for the answer! Does the optimizator during using partial index make desission only by comparison of where operands and index and does not go to some table filtration? I think yes, but can't find details in PostgreSQL documentation

If your query fulfills the index condition of partial index along with include, it doesn't have to go to perform table scan to fetch data. Needless to say, table has to be analyzed after creating index.
You can read below documentation
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html

I'd say that the index with INCLUDE speeds up things if the table has only these two columns. If there are more, the * would select them all, and you can no longer get an index-only scan.

The INCLUDE is adding additional columns to an index, without indexing them. So - creation or update of the index will be more expensive than one without. Scanning many items from the index will also probably be slower because more disk or memory needs to be accessed.
The advantage is if you want only the included columns then PostgreSQL might be able to avoid fetching the main table pages at all. This might though:
SELECT status FROM some_table WHERE ... <indexable checks>

Obviously in your example you are INCLUDEing a column that you then filter on anyway, so I can't think of any scenario where that makes sense.

The fact that the WHERE clause on the index fixes "status" to have a single value for rows found via that index does not cause PostgreSQL to assume that that is the value it will have.  Logically it seems like it could do that assumption, but it just doesn't.  So if "status" occurs in the select list, then you need to INCLUDE "status" into the index otherwise index-only-scan would not work.  But if "status" is included only in the WHERE clause of the query in a way which matches the WHERE clause of the index, then that does not inhibit an index-only-scan as the reference gets optimized away.
